# How can I speed up application of Log(x+1) to a sparse array in Julia

Tags: optimization, sparse-matrix, julia

A sparse matrix in Julia only stores nonzero elements.

Some functions, such as `log(x+1)` (in all bases),
map zero to zero, and thus don't need to be applied to those zero elements.
(I think we would call this a [Monoid homomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid#Monoid_homomorphisms).)

How can I use this fact to speed up an operation?

Example code:

```
X = sprand(10^4,10^4, 10.0^-5, rand)
function naiveLog2p1(N::SparseMatrixCSC{Float64,Int64})
    log2(1+N) |> sparse
end
```

Running:

```
@time naiveLog2p1(X)
```

Output is:

```
elapsed time: 2.580125482 seconds (2289 MB allocated, 6.86% gc time in 3 pauses with 0 full sweep)
```

On a second time (so that the function is expected to be already compiled):

```
elapsed time: 2.499118888 seconds (2288 MB allocated, 8.17% gc time in 3 pauses with 0 full sweep)
```

Little change, presumably cos it is so simple to compile.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure that you are aware that the build in `log1p` takes advance of this
```
julia> @time log1p(X);
elapsed time: 4.81e-5 seconds (93 kB allocated)
```

Comment: @andreasnoackjensen however log1p(X) is the natural logarithm

Comment: I can see that you are asking for all bases now, but you can probably follow the approach used in the definition of log1p for other bases as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [sparse nonzeros function](http://julia-demo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/sparse.html#Base.nonzeros).

> **`nonzeros(A)`**
>
> Return a vector of the structural nonzero values in sparse matrix `A`. This includes zeros that are explicitly stored in the sparse
>   matrix. The returned vector points directly to the internal nonzero
>   storage of `A`, and any modifications to the returned vector will mutate
>   `A` as well.

You can use this as below:

```
function improvedLog2p1(N::SparseMatrixCSC{Float64,Int64})
    M = copy(N)
    ms = nonzeros(M) #Creates a view, 
    ms = log2(1+ms) #changes to ms, change M
    M
end


@time improvedLog2p1(X)
```

running for the first time output is:

```
 elapsed time: 0.002447847 seconds (157 kB allocated)
```

running for the second time output is:

```
 0.000102335 seconds (109 kB allocated)
```

That is a 4 orders of magnitude improvement in speed and memory use.

Comment: `nonzeros` does not create a view, and all this function does is copy N

Comment: @IainDunning:
The documentation says it does. "any modifications to the returned vector will mutate A as well."
That is (the python) definition of a view (is the julia one different?). 
My experimentation shows it does also

Comment: That is worth Knowing. I'll do some research and enhance my answer (Checked and It is the same in the 3.0 docs)

Comment: Sorry I spoke too soon. You are assigning the view to `ms`, but then replacing `ms` with the new value. You aren't assigning to the matrix, you are just rebinding what `ms` points to.

Comment: Thus explaining the higher memory use. (and perhaps slightly higher speed), of my solution  over yours?

Comment: Definitely the higher memory use, and yeah unclear with the speed.

Comment: Just replace that line with `for i = 1:length(ms); ms[i] = log2(1+ms[i]); end`

Answer (score 2):

As per suggestion of the Julia manual on "Sparse matrix operations" I would convert the sparse matrix into a dense one using `findnz()`, do the log operations on the values and the reconstruc the sparse matrix with `sparse()`.

```
function improvedLog2p1(N::SparseMatrixCSC{Float64,Int64})
    I,J,V = findnz(N)
    return sparse(I,J,log2(1+V))
end

@time improvedLog2p1(X)
elapsed time: 0.000553508 seconds (473288 bytes allocated)
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be to actually operate on the inside of the data structure itself:

```
mysparselog(N::SparseMatrixCSC) =
    SparseMatrixCSC(N.m, N.n, copy(N.colptr), copy(N.rowval), log2(1+N.nzval))
```

Note that if you want to operate on the sparse matrix in place, which would be fairly often in practice I imagine, this would be a zero-memory operation. Benchmarking reveals this performs similar to the @Oxinabox answer, as it is about the same in terms of memory operations (although that answer doesn't actually return the new matrix, as shown by the `mean` output):

```
with warmup times removed:

naiveLog2p1
elapsed time: 1.902405905 seconds (2424151464 bytes allocated, 10.35% gc time)
mean(M) => 0.005568094618997372

mysparselog
elapsed time: 0.022551705 seconds (24071168 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.025841895 seconds (24071168 bytes allocated)
mean(M) => 0.005568094618997372

improvedLog2p1
elapsed time: 0.018682775 seconds (32068160 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.027129497 seconds (32068160 bytes allocated)
mean(M) => 0.004995127985160583
```

Comment: Could you clarify: "although that answer doesn't actually return the new matrix)?"